# Python : convert a hex string

Tags: python

//Duplicated question are deleted.

I would like to convert a hex string like this:

```
b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00NR09G05164\x00' //This is what I've received from socket
```

To something like:

```
0f0000004e52303947303531363400
```

How can I achieve this using Python?

Comment: Do you want the result to be a character string of hex digits, or a byte string of binary values? In other words, by `0f0000004e52303947303531363400` do you mean a string of length 15 bytes or 30 bytes?

Comment: You should not re-post your questions; instead, edit your closed question and request a re-open next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `binascii.hexlify()`:

```
In [25]: strs=b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00NR09G05164\x00'

In [26]: import binascii

In [27]: binascii.hexlify(strs)
Out[27]: b'0f0000004e52303947303531363400'
```

Comment: You voted to close the exact same question as NARQ 20 min ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292006/

Comment: @AshRj that question originally looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14292006/2
I guess It was edited after that.

Comment: is the (b'0f0000004e52303947303531363400') can be converted to ascii?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, it is just `b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00NR09G05164\x00'.hex()`.