# How to : Python Convert Bytes to Readable ASCII/Unicode

Tags: python

this is the bytes i have received,and i would like to convert 
byte[5] + byte[6] + byte[7] + byte[8] to ASCII readable text.

```
s=b'0f0000004e52303947303531363400'
```

bytes[5]~[8] ASCII/UNICODE is NR09

please help thanks.

Comment: Is this an assignment or something? Third time I've seen that code today.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292349/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292006/

Comment: @DanielB: Maybe they're on opposite sides of the connection. *runs*

Answer (score 14):

```
bytes.fromhex(s[4*2:8*2].decode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
//'NR09'
```

Btw, this would be much easier if you didn't use the conversion from [Python : convert a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292349/)

In that question you have:

```
b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00NR09G05164\x00'
```

So you can do

```
c = b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00NR09G05164\x00'
c[4:8].decode("ascii")
//'NR09'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rc@xxxxx:~$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s=b'0f0000004e52303947303531363400'
>>> s.decode("hex")[4:8]
'NR09'
```

Comment: 2.x doesn't use the `b` prefix by default, so I'm inclined to believe that 3.x is in use.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams edited with a copy paster (on osx)

Comment: This gives me the following error in python3: "LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs"